# Wcf client/server Login using facebook connect

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, facebook

Is it possible to use the facebook connect platform, which frees webmasters from the need of creating their own login mechanism, with a wcf client/server applications as a login?

If this can be easily done, It can save me some precious time implementing my own login and credentials mechanism. 
Besides - having facebook's login as your login mechanism frees you from worrying about storing users' passwords securely on your db, since all the credentials stuff is kept on facebook's servers ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be pretty easy to use one of the existing .NET Facebook Connect APIs to perform the authentication yourself.

One such API can be found here: http://fbconnectauth.codeplex.com/

And here is a quick tutorial on how to implement a custom WCF credentials validator:

http://nayyeri.net/custom-username-and-password-authentication-in-wcf-3-5

One thing to consider, however, is that Facebook Connect requires the user to interactively accept your application's request to validate their credentials. So this would need to be incorporated into your application.